# I have a stopwatch in reactjs, how can I add each number into some sort of array to show each number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a stopwatch using react. My stopwatch starts from 0 and stops at the press of the space button with componenDidMount and componentWillMount. My issue is, I can't seem to figure out how to create some sort of list with the numbers the stopwatch returns. I've created:

```
  times = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      myArray: [...previousState.myArray, this.state.milliSecondsElapsed]
    }));

  };
```

and then in render() to print it.

`<h1>{this.times}</h1>`

What I'm trying to do is to create some sort of array that'll keep track of milliSecondsElapsed in my handleStart and handleStop method.

Here's what I have.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js';

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      milliSecondsElapsed: 0,
      timerInProgress: false // state to detect whether timer has started
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
  }

  textInput = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };
  updateState(e) {
    this.setState({})
    this.setState({ milliSecondsElapsed: e.target.milliSecondsElapsed });
  }

  keyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      // some logic to assess stop/start of timer
      if (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed === 0) {
        this.startBtn.click();
      } else if (this.state.timerInProgress === false) {
        this.startBtn.click();
      } else {
        this.stopBtn.click();
      }
    }
  };

  handleStart = () => {
    if (this.state.timerInProgress === true) return;

    this.setState({
      milliSecondsElapsed: 0
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          milliSecondsElapsed: this.state.milliSecondsElapsed + 1,
          timerInProgress: true
        },
        () => {
          this.stopBtn.focus();
        }
      );
    }, 10);
  };
  handleStop = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        timerInProgress: false
      },
      () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.startBtn.focus();
      }
    );
  };

  times = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      myArray: [...previousState.myArray, this.state.milliSecondsElapsed]
    }));

  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Layout>
          <div className="index" align='center'>
            <input 
              value={this.state.milliSecondsElapsed/100}
              onChange={this.updateState}
              ref={this.textInput}
              readOnly={true}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleStart} ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}>
              START
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.handleStop} ref={(ref) => (this.stopBtn = ref)}>
              STOP
            </button>
            <h1>{this.state.milliSecondsElapsed/100}</h1>
          </div>

        
      </Layout>
    


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save the elapsed time into state? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Oh, I see. `this.times` is a function that updates state. What exactly do you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`this.times` is a function that only updates state, it doesn't return any renderable JSX.

```
times = () => {
  this.setState((previousState) => ({
    myArray: [...previousState.myArray, this.state.milliSecondsElapsed]
  }));
};
```

## Solution

1. Create a `myArray` state.

   ```
   this.state = {
     myArray: [], // <-- add initial empty array
     milliSecondsElapsed: 0,
     timerInProgress: false // state to detect whether timer has started
   };
   ```
2. Move the state update logic from `this.times` to `this.handleStop`.

   ```
   handleStop = () => {
     this.setState(
       (previousState) => ({
         timerInProgress: false,
         myArray: [
           ...previousState.myArray, // <-- shallow copy existing data
           this.state.milliSecondsElapsed / 100 // <-- add new time
         ]
       }),
       () => {
         clearInterval(this.timer);
         this.startBtn.focus();
       }
     );
   };
   ```
3. Render the array of elapsed times as a comma separated list.

   ```
   <div>{this.state.myArray.join(", ")}</div>
   ```

Full code

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myArray: [],
      milliSecondsElapsed: 0,
      timerInProgress: false // state to detect whether timer has started
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
  }

  textInput = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  updateState(e) {
    this.setState({ milliSecondsElapsed: e.target.milliSecondsElapsed });
  }

  keyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      // some logic to assess stop/start of timer
      if (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed === 0) {
        this.startBtn.click();
      } else if (this.state.timerInProgress === false) {
        this.startBtn.click();
      } else {
        this.stopBtn.click();
      }
    }
  };

  handleStart = () => {
    if (this.state.timerInProgress === true) return;

    this.setState({
      milliSecondsElapsed: 0
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          milliSecondsElapsed: this.state.milliSecondsElapsed + 1,
          timerInProgress: true
        },
        () => {
          this.stopBtn.focus();
        }
      );
    }, 10);
  };

  handleStop = () => {
    this.setState(
      (previousState) => ({
        timerInProgress: false,
        myArray: [
          ...previousState.myArray,
          this.state.milliSecondsElapsed / 100
        ]
      }),
      () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.startBtn.focus();
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="index" align="center">
          <input
            value={this.state.milliSecondsElapsed / 100}
            onChange={this.updateState}
            ref={this.textInput}
            readOnly={true}
          />
          <button
            onClick={this.handleStart}
            ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}
          >
            START
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.handleStop} ref={(ref) => (this.stopBtn = ref)}>
            STOP
          </button>
          <h1>{this.state.milliSecondsElapsed / 100}</h1>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.myArray.join(", ")}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit i-have-a-stopwatch-in-reactjs-how-can-i-add-each-number-into-some-sort-of-array]

Comment: Was trying to get back into a project I was working on before the semester.. thanks!

Comment: @AustinStory How many semesters has it been? :p React has generally shifted *away* from class-based components.

Comment: About a year. I had an idea for a website after I took the class, then got distracted with other work.